# Null check for member property is not working (mdx)

Tags: properties, null, mdx

I have problems with a null check on a user defined member property in mdx.

The property is of type datetime in cube. If I check the value in mdx, it will return the date or null if no value was provided.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[TheValue] as MyMember.Properties("MyProperty")   //returns (null) or date, e.g. 01.04.2015
```

However I cannot null-check the value.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[TheValueExists] as IIF(ISEMPTY(MyMember.Properties("MyProperty")), false, true)
```

always evaluates to true, which is wrong, and the same with 'is null' always returns an error. Would be thankful for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that made it work was adding the **typed**-overload:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[TheValueExists] as IIF(ISEMPTY([MyMember.Properties("MyProperty", typed)), 
    false, true)
```